# Snowflake split INT row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following data in snowflake

| Account ID | Ad ID | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2 |
| D2 | C2 | 4 |

I am looking to split the INT column into multiple rows depending on the value in each cell so I am left with the following:

| Account ID | Ad ID | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | 1 |
| D2 | C2 | 1 |
| D2 | C2 | 1 |
| D2 | C2 | 1 |
| D2 | C2 | 1 |

Can someone please advise how I would go about doing something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
select Account_ID,Ad_ID, 1  New_Value
from mytable,
lateral flatten ( SPLIT( REPEAT('x',New_Value - 1), 'x' )  );

+------------+-------+-----------+
| ACCOUNT_ID | AD_ID | NEW_VALUE |
+------------+-------+-----------+
| A1         | B1    |         1 |
| A1         | B1    |         1 |
| D2         | C2    |         1 |
| D2         | C2    |         1 |
| D2         | C2    |         1 |
| D2         | C2    |         1 |
+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: You are my hero sir, thank you!